# Excel Macro - Using For Each Loop To Hyperlink Back to Main / Index Pages

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many sheets (365++) . Meanwhile there are many examples VBA code that allows macro **creating hyperlinks from index pages to the contents** ; however there are totally zero examples of **creating hyperlinks from contents back to index pages.**

Using the loop thru solutions, I can get the code to work BUT *it only works for existing active pages whereas I need it to loop every single sheet range "A1" in the workbook to link it back to main pages*

Here are code as follows:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'Dummy data to test for loop
        'ws.Range("A1").Value = "Dummy"
        
        'Only works for existing sheets,need to loop for each loops of each sheets
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Main!A1", TextToDisplay:="Back to Main Sheet"
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a loop through all worksheets, but inside that loop you reference only the active sheet, without ever changing the active sheet.

You don't need ActiveSheet or Select. Instead, use the `ws` sheet from the loop to qualify the sheet for the `.Hyperlinks.Add` and for the anchor range. Like this:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A1"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Main!A1", TextToDisplay:="Back to Main Sheet"
    Next ws

End Sub
```